# Tabpage(Tabcontrol) choice when loading form

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

How can I when loading the main form in which there is a TabControl I want to do something that used to be displayed tabPges

In general I want to be the default when loading tabPges2 form and other tabPges be disabled.

[**Image**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a5jzktp7zkb5lm/tabpage.PNG?m=)

Comment: are you asking about TabControl from WPF or Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the selected page using the tab control's SelectedTab property:

```
myTabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
```

Comment: There is no property selectedTab.

Comment: I am talking about the native WinForms control. What are you referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake you're saying is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide/show tab pages because as read from MSDN

> TabPage controls are constrained by their container, so some of the
>   properties inherited from the Control base class will have no effect,
>   including Top, Height, Left, Width, Show, and Hide.
>
> The tabs in a TabControl are part of the TabControl but not parts of
>   the individual TabPage controls. Members of the TabPage class, such as
>   the ForeColor property, affect only the client rectangle of the tab
>   page, but not the tabs. Additionally, the Hide method of the TabPage
>   will not hide the tab. To hide the tab, you must remove the TabPage
>   control from the TabControl.TabPages collection.

so on `Load` event remove all tab pages and add them later when needed. Unfortunately you can't disable them either. There is only not-the-best workaround, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984352%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)